# Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'> when call tf.gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am creating a monte carlo simulation to price option via tensorflow. When I try to call second gradient to calculate gamma, it threw an error that:

```
Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

When I run the code with blstfPricer:

```
pricerobj = OptionPricer()

blspricer = pricerobj.blstfPricer()

price = blspricer(100,110,2,0.2,0.03,0)
```

Everything works well. But when I call:

```
pricer = pricerobj.tfmcPricer(TFMonteCarloSimulatorType.GBM,enable_greeks = True)

price = pricer(100,110,2.0,0.2,0.03,0,0,100000,365 * 2)
```

It will throw an error that:

```
Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

I checked that the issue was caused by

```
gamma = tf.gradients(greeks[0],[spot])
```

Some one can help me with it?

Please see my code below:

```
    class TFMonteCarloSimulator(object):    
        def __init__(self, SimulatorType):
            if not isinstance(SimulatorType, TFMonteCarloSimulatorType):
                raise Exception("Please use defined Simulator Type from class TFMonteCarloSimulatorType")
            self.simulatorType = SimulatorType
        def _GBMSimulation(self):
            spot = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            strike = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            dt = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            vol = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            timeToMaturity = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            dw = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            miu = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            div = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            pricer = spot * tf.cumprod(tf.exp((miu - div - (vol ** 2) / 2) * dt + vol * tf.sqrt(dt) * dw), axis=1)
            return (spot, strike, dt, vol, miu, div, dw, pricer,timeToMaturity)
        def createSimulator(self):
            if self.simulatorType == TFMonteCarloSimulatorType.GBM:
                (spot, strike, dt, vol, miu, div, dw, pricer,timeToMaturity) = self._GBMSimulation()
                def simulator(S, K, TTM, volatility, drift, dividend, seed, Nsimulation, Ndays):
                    if seed != 0:
                        np.random.seed(seed)
                    rndMatrix = np.random.randn(Nsimulation, Ndays)

                    with tf.Session() as sess:
                        timeDelta = TTM / Ndays
                        res = sess.run(pricer,{
                            spot: S,
                            strike: K,
                            miu:drift,
                            div:dividend,
                            vol:volatility,
                            dt:timeDelta,
                            timeToMaturity:TTM,
                            dw:rndMatrix                    
                        })
                        return res
                return simulator
            else:
                return None



    class OptionPricer(TFMonteCarloSimulator):
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def blstfPricer(self, enable_greeks = True):
            spot = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            strike = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            dt = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            vol = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            ir = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            div = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            ndf = tfp.distributions.Normal(0,1).cdf
            d1 = (tf.log(spot/strike) + (ir + (vol ** 2)/2) * dt) / (vol * tf.sqrt(dt))
            d2 = d1 - vol * tf.sqrt(dt)
            price = spot * tf.exp(-div * dt) * ndf(d1) - strike * tf.exp(-ir * dt) * ndf(d2)
            targets = [price]
            if enable_greeks:
                greeks = tf.gradients(price, [spot, vol, ir, dt])
                gamma = tf.gradients(ys = greeks[0],xs = [spot])
                targets += [greeks, gamma]
            def execute(S,K, TTM, imVol, IR, Div):
                with tf.Session() as sess:
                    res = sess.run(targets,
                                  {spot:S,
                                   strike:K,
                                   ir:IR,
                                   vol:imVol,
                                   div:Div,
                                   dt:TTM
                                  })
                    return res
            return execute

        def tfmcPricer(self, simType,enable_greeks = True):
            if simType == TFMonteCarloSimulatorType.GBM:
                (spot, strike, dt, vol, miu, div, dw, pricer, timeToMaturity) = super(OptionPricer, self)._GBMSimulation()
                payoff = tf.maximum(pricer[:,-1] - strike, 0)
                price = tf.exp(-miu * timeToMaturity) * tf.reduce_mean(payoff)
                targets = [price]
                if enable_greeks:
                    greeks = tf.gradients(price, [spot, vol, miu,timeToMaturity])
                    gamma = tf.gradients(greeks[0],[spot])
                    targets += [greeks]
                    targets += [gamma]
                def execute(S, K, TTM, volatility, drift, dividend,seed, Nsimulation,Ndays):
                    if seed != 0:
                        np.random.seed(seed)
                    rndMatrix = np.random.randn(Nsimulation, Ndays)
                    with tf.Session() as sess:
                        timedelta = TTM / Ndays 
                        res = sess.run(targets,
                                          {
                                            timeToMaturity:TTM,
                                            spot:S,
                                            strike:K,
                                            dt:timedelta,
                                            vol:volatility,
                                            miu:drift, 
                                            div:dividend,
                                            dw:rndMatrix
                                          }

                                      )
                        return res
                return execute
            else:
                return None
```

Comment: The reason for that is that there is some non-differentiable operation in the computation, so the gradient ends up being `None`. In principle I don't see anything non-differentiable in your code, but you are trying to compute the gradient of a gradient. This is in principle possible, but the first gradient may be using some non-differentiable operation in its computation, in which case the second gradient would not be computable (note when I say "non-differentiable" here I mean "without a defined gradient in TF").